# PyCharm code completion setup for underscore - less priority for protected and mangled names?

Tags: python, pydev, pycharm, code-completion

I am using PyCharm but I do not like default code completion which shows `_protected` and `__mangled` names higher than `public`.

How can I force to show names starting with **underscore** at the bottom of code completion list and public at the top?

Some editors like PyDev is doing it much better without configuration.

---

Screen asked by @jole showing my problem:

[image: Current code completion invalid prioritization which I want change]

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/code-completion.html? Are you sorting by "relevance"?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have already read this but it not helps - only shows that PyCharm is not able to do this simple thing. I do not what mean "relevance" - it is too magic be understand by anyone - I set relevance but it shows what is not relevant for me - for me sort order should be frequency, public, private, mangled, alphabetic :)

Comment: Please don't roll back edits without good reason - this question is about [tag:pycharm], [tag:pydev] may be an example of what you want but is otherwise irrelevant.

Comment: Going back on topic, can you show a screenshot where PyCharm shows double-underscore prefixed items higher than regular ones? PyCharm already has built-in logic to deprioritize such items.

Comment: @yole No problem always I see such results :)

Comment: @yole I attached screen I choose threading but  it can be others modules.

Answer (score 4):

This is not configurable in PyCharm; there is [an open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-3674) for changing the default behavior of the completion in this context.

Comment: Detailed prioritization in PyCharm will be welcome in settings - frequency, public, private, mangled, alpha will be welcome also some exceptions in format `module.something`. Public should be first since it should be used first.

Comment: Making something configurable makes sense when there are valid reasons for different people to prefer different choices. I don't believe that is the case here. Completion does already take into account the frequency of using particular variants.

Comment: Just putting public first without any other special settings would be a huge usability improvement. Right now, single "_" items always appear first.