# Making imported modules or imported methods in single file module private

Tags: python

When I have a single file module relying on a 3rd party module or method from a 3rd party module which is imported in the single file module, then I have access to the 3rd party module or method when I import the single file module. I want to prevent that, my suggestion was to import the 3rd party module or method and renaming them with an underscore in front. Would that be a good idea, what other options do I have.

**Example 1**:

```
# this is a single file module called DemoModule.py
import numpy as np


def calculate_something():
    x = np.cos(0)

    return x
```

Now when I import DemoModule I do not only have access to `calculate_something`, but I also have access to everything numpy has to offer as well. Would this be a good way to avoid that situation:

```
# this is a single file module called DemoModule.py
import numpy as _np


def calculate_something():
    x = _np.cos(0)

    return x
```

**Example 2**:

```
# this is a single file module called DemoModule.py

from numpy import cos


def calculate_something():
    x = cos(0)

    return x
```

Now when I import DemoModule I do not only have access to calculate_something, but I also have access to `cos`. Would this be a good way to avoid that situation:

```
# this is a single file module called DemoModule.py

from numpy import cos as _cos


def calculate_something():
    x = _cos(0)

    return x
```

***Edit***:

A run from the command line

```
In[2]: import DemoModule
In[3]: DemoModule.np.cos(1)
Out[3]: 0.54030230586813977
```

Comment: I am missing the use case for this.  The module doing the importing is going to get access to numpy if they want it.  What problem are you fixing?

Comment: @StephenRauch When I import DemoModule then I have in the scope  where I imported DemoModule access to nump or cos, I want to prevent that.

Comment: You are aware that using underscores for *private* variables is only a python naming convention, it does not change how anything functions

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes I am

Comment: I realize you want to prevent that.  What I am unclear on, is what problem do you think will be fixed when you do that.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing the point, but when you import DemoModule, do you actually have access to numpy?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, see my edit from a few seconds ago.

Comment: Ah yes as `DemoModule.np` but not `np`, so isn't this already keeping the namespace unpolluted, what's the problem as Stephen says?

Comment: I still don't get the point as far as I'm concerned. However you rename numpy in your `DemoModule`, someone importing `DemoModule` will still have access to it, __and__ will be able to import numpy by himself anyway. So to repeat Stephen Rauch and  Chris_Rands questions : __what is your problem with numpy being accessible from your module ?__  Why do you care at all ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands and bruno_desthuilliers It will pop up as well in my auto-complete in PyCharm when browsing for methods in DemoModule.

Comment: That's a crucial detail, so does PyCharm autocomplete methods with leading underscores? I know that the Python interpreter does not

Comment: @Chris_Rands I think that is configurable, but I am not sure. However at the moment I got used to underscore for private methods, hence my initially suggested solution. However maybe I should stop worrying and just continue with what I am doing.

Comment: relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766414/pycharm-code-completion-setup-for-underscore-less-priority-for-protected-and-m

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks , but that still implies I should write `import numpy as _np`, not?

Comment: And yet another XY problem...

Answer (score 3):

First the usual disclaimer: Python has no concept of enforced "privacy" - the single leading underscore is only a naming convention saying "let's pretend you don't know this exists" (I assume you know this already but better to make things clear right from the start).

And the canonical answer is : define the `__all__` attribute of your module with the names you want to publicly expose - every other name in the module should then be considered by users as "private". You *can* double this with a single-leading-underscore (`import foo as _foo`) if you really want to make the point clear but that's perhaps a bit over the top.